# Difference between cause of/for and reason for/of

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

The question is a multiple choice

> I don't think you have any real cause _____ complaint.

Choices are ( of / for / with / on)

Clearly it's either of or for. In my model answer it should be "for"

> "Revenge was the main _____ the fire.

Choices ( reason for / cause of / reason of )

It should be "reason for".

There must be a difference between cause and reason in their usages
and also prepositions ?

Comment: They're usually pretty much interchangeable, but personally I think ***the cause of*** something more strongly implies *the actual agent*, where ***the reason for*** it might simply be something making it more likely that the agent would do whatever it was. That's why I'd tend to choose ***reason for*** in the second example, but it's a bad question if it implies that ***cause of*** is somehow "incorrect" (it's actually fine). Note that *cause for complaint* is something of an established idiom (*You have no cause for disagreement / disagreeing*, for example, isn't very idiomatic).

Answer (score 3):

> cause

usually describes **how** *something* happened.

> reason

usually describes **why** *something* happened.

> Revenge was the main *reason for* the fire. *(why)*
>   Spilled gasoline was the *cause of* the fire.  *(how)*

"Cause" can use either "for" and "of" depending on circumstances.

> cause **for** complaint
>   cause **of** the complaint

"Reason" uses "for" in order to explain *something*.

> reason **for** complaining
>   reason **to** complain